# Aggregate similar row

Tags: aggregate, oracle9i

Suppose I've a table like this:

```
 NAME   REF1   REF2   DRCT
  A    (null)   Ra     D1
  A      Rb   (null)   D1
  A    (null)   Rc     D2
  B      Rd   (null)   D3
  B    (null)   Re     D3
```

I want aggregate this table in something like:

```
NAME   REF1   REF2   DRCT
 A      Rb     Ra     D1
 A    (null)   Rc     D2
 B      Rd     Re     D3
```

As you can see, i want aggregate each row with same name. I've search through COALESCE and various aggregate functions but I haven't found what i was looking for. Any idea?

Comment: What values can REF1 and REF2 take for a given NAME and DRCT? Following your example, for records with NAME=A and DRCT=D1, REF1 can only take (null) or Rb, or is it possible that REF1 be, Rx?

Comment: each value is allowed. But only one columns at once is defined for each row. If ref1 is defined, ref2 will be null. And viceversa.

Comment: Then, I think my answer will work for you. But I will think in an easier way to do it.

Comment: I would be really grateful

Comment: But have you seen if my current answer solves your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what I ask in my previous comment is true, (only null or a given value for REF1 and REF2 for each NAME, DRCT pair), this seems to work:

```
select NAME, M_REF1, M_REF2, DRCT 
from (
    select A.NAME, coalesce(A.REF1, B.REF1) m_REF1, 
       coalesce(A.REF2, B.REF2) m_REF2, A.REF1 A_REF1, B.REF1 B_REF1,
       A.REF2 A_REF2, B.REF2 B_REF2, A.DRCT
    from Table1 A JOIN Table1 B on A.NAME = B.NAME AND A.DRCT = B.DRCT)
    WHERE A_REF1 = m_REF1 AND B_REF2 = m_REF2
UNION
select A.NAME, A.REF1, A.REF2, A.DRCT 
FROM Table1 A JOIN
     (select NAME, DRCT, COUNT(*)
      from Table1
      group by NAME, DRCT
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) B ON A.NAME = B.NAME AND A.DRCT = B.DRCT;
```

The union is used because the rows with only one record are not included in the first SELECT.

But this is somewhat simpler, and works too:

```
select A.NAME, coalesce(A.REF1, B.REF1) M_REF1, coalesce(A.REF2,B.REF2) M_REF2,A.DRCT
from Table1 A LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 B ON A.DRCT = B.DRCT AND A.NAME = B.NAME 
WHERE NVL2(A.REF1,0,1) = 1 AND NVL2(B.REF1,0,1) =0 
      AND NVL2(A.REF2,0,1) = 0 AND NVL2(B.REF2,0,1) = 1
UNION
select A.NAME, A.REF1, A.REF2, A.DRCT 
FROM Table1 A JOIN
 (select NAME, DRCT, COUNT(*)
  from Table1
  group by NAME, DRCT
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) B ON A.NAME = B.NAME AND A.DRCT = B.DRCT;
```

Comment: I'm trying right now. I see a strange where clause, second and third AND are equals. What do you mean?

Comment: What if I need to translate the two-columns argumentation on four-columns? I just need to add two couple of AND in where clause or I need even two further left join?

Comment: Maybe you have to do both, but I've no time to think in it right now. I'll try later, and let you know.